# Can you come into combat in tiny death star?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Can you actually attack planets in tiny death star? And do you ever come into more conflict with rebels then just their spies and hero's?

Comment: Do you have something that states you *could* do this?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can´t attack any planet. The only thing you can do is to explore other planets searching for useful resources for your progess.